# Does a "for XXX use" clause make any sense for a null record?

Tags: ada

I have been tasked with added representation (rep) clauses for all our record types which will be sent in  messages to another processor. It's a different CPU manufacturer, compiler & programming language, so there is a danger of misalignment/misinterpretation.

Obviously, `type XXX is record` requires a `for XXX use` with the appropriate byte & bit data for each field.

What about `type null_record is null record;` ?

```
for null_record use
   null;
end record;
```

does not compile and doesn't really seem to make sense.

The boss is pushing for 100% rep clause, with `'size`, `'alignment` `'Object_size`, `Value_size` and `pragma pack`, but surely that makes no sense for a null record?

Comment: Pretty sure `pragma Pack` won’t do much good, given you have rep clauses.

Comment: I was wondering that too. Much of the existing code has both `for XXX use` with byte & bit positions, ***and*** `pragma pack` Belt & braces, I guess

Comment: Sometimes you want a block of "stuff" -- for [eg] preservation of some value-set -- like say a record from some other system that needs to be preserved, so a `Size` attribute-definition definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would make sense if a `record representation clause` forced a `component clause` for all components. In that case the compiler would detect any changes to the `record definition`, and thus force you to take a look at the `representation clause` as well. *Of course, that is not the case, so you're right, it doesn't make much sense.*

However, if your boss really insists, the correct syntax is:

```
for null_record use
record
end record;
```

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 I would never have thunk that (+1)